# post curl to rest interface using a shell script

Tags: shell, rest, curl

i try to create a script that send a messages from nagios servers to a rest api in json.

i try this:

```
/usr/bin/curl  \
--header "Content-type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '{"u_id": "$NOTIFY_SERVICEPROBLEMID", "u_date_time" : "$NOTIFY_SHORTDATETIME", \
"u_state" : "$NOTIFY_SERVICESHORTSTATE", "u_host" : "$NOTIFY_HOSTNAME", "u_address" : "$NOTIFY_HOSTADDRESS", \
"u_description" : "$NOTIFY_HOSTALIAS/$NOTIFY_SERVICEDESC is $NOTIFY_SERVICESTATE"}' \
https://my-rest_api
```

but it is not working.. The variables that start with $NOTIFY should expand.

I am wondering where should I end the  single quotes since single quotes must be part of the json that is being sent to rest api.

thank you

Comment: strings within single quotes do not expand variables, that's how the shell works!

Comment: I know. that is exactly my questions.. how can i achieve this.. anyway I have found a workaround as this:
`json=$(echo -e "{\"name\":\"$NOTIFY_OMD_SITE\", \"u_id\":\"$NOTIFY_SERVICEPROBLEMID\", \"u_date_time\":\"$NOTIFY_SHORTDATETIME\", \"u_state\":\"$NOTIFY_SERVICESHORTSTATE\", \"u_host\":\"$NOTIFY_HOSTNAME\", \"u_address\":\"$NOTIFY_HOSTADDRESS\", \"u_description\":\"$NOTIFY_HOSTALIAS/$NOTIFY_SERVICEDESC is $NOTIFY_SERVICESTATE\"}")`

then 

`curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$json" https://my-restapi`

is there other way?